# Creating Regular Expression with Variable in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am a bit new to Regular Expressions. I am trying to create a Regular Expression in Java with a variable inside.

I would like to match "var", "(var)", "[var]", or "{var}" and any case variation of the variable var.

I have tried this, and it seems to have an exception:
`java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 20`

Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix and improve this?

```
String s = "[Tom] The rest of the title";
String v = "Tom";

s = s.replaceAll("(?i)[({/[]*" + v + "[)}\]]*", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Should `[Tom)` match in your example?

Comment: @AndrewRueckert Thanks for the response, no it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
String s = "[Tom] The rest of the title";
String v = "Tom";

String myRegexp = String.format("(?i)\\[%s\\]|\\{%s\\}|\\(%s\\)|%s", v,v,v,v);
System.out.println(myRegexp);

s = s.replaceAll(myRegexp, "");
System.out.println(s);
```

This line:

```
String myRegexp = String.format("(?i)\\[%s\\]|\\{%s\\}|\\(%s\\)|%s", v,v,v,v);
```

builds a simple regular expression:
 `(?i)\[Tom\]|\{Tom\}|\(Tom\)|Tom`
All braces: `{}[]()` are special characters in regular expressions, and they have to be escaped by `\` character (in Java string it must be `\\`).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Does this work for "too cool for school" to "[Too Cool for School] Hello"? It doesn't seem to remove this from the title!

Comment: Yes it works if you replace `Tom` with a new string and assign it to `v` ==> `String v = "Too Cool for School";`

Comment: great answer! This is exactly what I was looking for, but extending it a bit more, what about removing all special characters around "Tom"? For example, the string could be something like "{[[Tom]]}" and I would want to replace the entire string with an empty string! Is it possible to remove all characters until an empty space on both sides?

Comment: How would you match any number of special characters on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

Matching pairs of braces ( to ), { to }, etc. is going to be messy with regular expressions, since the relationship isn't built into the language. A naieve solution would be:

```
String s = "[Tom] The rest of the title (TOM] tom";
String v = "Tom";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(" + v + "\\)|\\{" + v + "\\}|\\[" + v + "\\]|(?![{(\\[])" + v + "(?![})\\]])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println('\'' + m.replaceAll("") + '\'');
// ' The rest of the title (TOM] '
```

The head-ache-y part of regular expressions in Java is that you need to *double escape* any literal characters with `\\`, since you want a literal backslash character to appear in the string that you're passing to the regex compiler.

Comment: Is there anything that's more readable / elegant that works for most of the cases?